# Does RAPIDS cuML library support Generalized Linear Models (GLMs)?

Tags: rapids

I think cuML does support GLMs because linear and logistic regressions are types of GLMs and cuML supports those. Best to be sure! https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml

If it is not supported, is it on the roadmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, RAPIDS currently supports GLM for single GPU, multi GPU, and multi-node environments.